# Extending front-end-template with custom RPC

Tags: rpc, substrate-front-end

My chain currently has a couple of custom RPC interfaces that I'd like to interact with using substrates front-end-template.
I'm aware that the src/config/common.json file requires modification, which currently looks like this:

```json
{
  "APP_NAME": "substrate-front-end-template",
  "CUSTOM_RPC_METHODS": {}
}
```

What is the correct syntax for defining my custom RPC here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the template will use the same format as the polkadot-js API since it will pass those through to the API itself, you can find [examples here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/rpc.custom)

And indeed, if I look at the front-end-template itself, [it uses that config](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/blob/e36c75de93a8fbd6a40b374129fbfa50a2bff16d/src/substrate-lib/SubstrateContext.js#L20) to pass it [through to the API](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/blob/e36c75de93a8fbd6a40b374129fbfa50a2bff16d/src/substrate-lib/SubstrateContext.js#L69) on init.